# Copy multiple Range from worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy multiple cells from one worksheet to another. I'm getting error message wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

```
Range("D10:D12,D15,D22,D25,D32:D33,D38:D42,D47:D50,D53,D55,D57,D63").Select
Range("G3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
'Range("I4").End(xlUp).Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "I", "AD").End(xlUp).Row
Range("I", "AD" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("I4", "AD").Select
```

Hoping for your help.

---

i tried using union but cannot come up with a solution. Here is the codes I have now

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, multiRange As Range

Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10:D12,D15,D22,D25,D32:D33,D38:D42,D47:D50,D53,D55,D57,D63")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3")
Set multiRange = Union(r1, r2)
Application.Union(r1, r2).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
'Range("I4").End(xlUp).Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Range("I" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("I4").Select
```

THE error message I'm know getting is That command cannot be used on multiple selections.
The Highlighted code is SELECTION.COPY

Comment: Please post the full error here.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "I", "AD").End(xlUp).Row` This is invalid. `Cells` expects 2 arguments only. It is either `Cells(Rows.Count, "I")` or `Cells(Rows.Count, "AD")`.

Comment: why is the first line in your code?  the next line supersedes it.  ... you should always fully qualify object properties and methods if possible ... use `Range("G3").Copy` instead of line 2 and line 3

Comment: The `Range("G3").Copy` is also a cell that I need to copy. please correct me if i'm wrong. so instead of `.select` i should replace it with `.copy`? and then delete the `selection.copy`?

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that Sheets("Sheet1") has sheet CodeName "Sheet1", and similar for Sheet3. (In general you should use sheet CodeName in your code).

```
Dim SourceArea As Range
Dim TargetArea As Range
Dim CopyRange As Range

Set CopyRange = Sheet1.Range("D10:D12,D15,D22,D25,D32:D33,D38:D42,D47:D50,D53,D55,D57,D63")

For Each SourceArea In CopyRange.Areas
    Set TargetArea = Sheet3.Range(SourceArea.Address)
    TargetArea.Value = SourceArea.Value
Next
```

Edit: The above will paste in Sheet3 in exactly the same locations as the ranges in Sheet1. If you want to paste to a different location, use Offset. For example if you want the top left cell in the target to be I20, then:

```
Set TargetArea = Sheet3.Range(SourceArea.Address).Offset(10,5)
```

Comment: On the range in `Sheet1.Range("D10:D12,D15,D22,D25,D32:D33,D38:D42,D47:D50,D53,D55,D57,D63")` can I add a cell here? and in this code where will be the data pasted in sheet3? Will it be pasted in "I"?